# Generating named lists in R

Tags: r

If I want to create a named list, where I have named literals, I can just do this:

```
list(foo=1,bar=2,baz=3)
```

If instead I want to make a list with arbitrary computation, I can use `lapply`, so for example:

```
lapply(list(1,2,3), function(x) x)
```

However, the list generated by `lapply` will always be a regular numbered list. Is there a way I can generate a list using a function like `lapply` with names.

My idea is something along the lines of:

```
lapply(list("foo","bar","baz"), function(key) {key=5}
```

==>

```
list(foo=5,bar=5,baz=5)
```

That way I don't have to have the keys and values as literals.

I do know that I could do this:

```
res = list()
for(key in list("foo","bar","baz") {
    res[key] <- 5;
}
```

But I don't like how I have to create a empty list and mutate it to fill it out.

Edit: I would also like to do some computation based on the key. Something like this:

```
lapply(c("foo","bar","baz"), function(key) {paste("hello",key)=5})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sapply` will use its argument for names if it is a character vector, so you can try:

```
sapply(c("foo","bar","baz"), function(key) 5, simplify=F)
```

Which produces:

```
$foo
[1] 5

$bar
[1] 5

$baz
[1] 5
```

Comment: Okay cool. Is it possible to do some computation on the key? Say if I wanted to do: `sapply(c("foo","bar","baz"), function(key) {paste("hello",key)=5}, simplify=F)`, or something like that.

Comment: @LeifAndersen, you can have computations, but they will only affect the value.  The key is fully determined by what you pass as the first argument to `sapply` (note you could just as easily pass `paste("hello", c("foo", ...))`).  You can also explicitly set names as MrFlick shows.

Comment: @LeifAndersen : yes you can also do computation on the key, but its nothing other than a for loop at that point: `sapply(c("foo","bar","baz"), function(key) setNames(list(5), paste("hello", key)), simplify=TRUE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)`

Comment: added as [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77631459/1870254)

Answer (score 3):

If your list has names in the first place, lapply will preserve them

```
lapply(list(a=1,b=2,c=3), function(x) x)
```

or you can set names before or after with `setNames()`

```
#before
lapply(setNames(list(1,2,3),c("foo","bar","baz")), function(x) x)

#after
setNames(lapply(list(1,2,3), function(x) x), c("foo","bar","baz"))
```

One other "option" is `Map()`. `Map` will try to take the names from the first parameter you pass in. You can ignore the value in the function and use it only for the side-effect of keeping the name

```
Map(function(a,b) 5, c("foo","bar","baz"), list(1:3))
```

But names cannot be changed during lapply/Map steps. They can only be copied from another location. if you need to mutate names, you'll have to do that as a separate step.

Comment: This lets me run some computation on the value, but not the key itself. Say I wanted to do something like: `lapply(c("foo","bar","baz"), function(key) {paste("hello",key)=5})`, is that possible?

Comment: You need two steps. `x<-c("foo","bar","baz"); setNames(lapply(x, function(x) 5), paste("hello", x))` You cannot change names during the `lapply()` call; you can only preserve names.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting MrFlick's use of setNames, here is a simple function that can do both:

```
list_zip = function(names, values) {
  values = rep(values, length.out = length(names))
  setNames(as.list(values), names)
}

list_zip(c("foo", "bar", "baz"), c(1,2,3))

list_zip(c("foo", "bar", "baz"), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to set the name of the returned list elements within the code computing each value, you have to return named length-1 lists from that code instead and get rid of the outer list layer. This can readily be achieved using `sapply`:

```r
x <- list(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)
x
#> $foo
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $bar
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $baz
#> [1] 3
sapply(names(x), function(key) setNames(list(x[[key]]^2), paste0(key, "_squared")), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#> $foo_squared
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $bar_squared
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $baz_squared
#> [1] 9
```

To get a named list in the first place `rlang::dots_list(..., .named=TRUE)` can sometimes be helpful (I am still searching for an equivalent in base R):

```r
foo <- 1
bar <- 2
baz <- 3

rlang::dots_list(foo, bar, baz, .named=TRUE)
#> $foo
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $bar
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $baz
#> [1] 3
```